# EditText.setText(String) throws array out of bounds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-geocoder

I have an app that gets the location address from geocoder it does the request inside a thread.
 When getActivity().runOnUiThread is called I already have the address response from geocoder inside a string variable and I check it to see if it is empty and start assign it's value to fields in the view:

```
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (isAdded())
                                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strAddress)){
                                        et.setFocusable(false);
                                        et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                                        et.setText(strAddress);
                                        et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                                                android.R.color.black));
                                        et.setFocusable(true);
                                        et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                                    } else {
                                        et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                                                android.R.color.black));
                                    }
                                etSource.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
```

on this line:

```
et.setText(strAddress);
```

The error

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: set span -1

is throw and it happens intermittently, why is this happening ?

**Edit as requested**

```
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1270)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
                                                                         at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
                                                                         at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.resetDragAcceleratorState(Editor.java:5689)
                                                                         at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.resetTouchOffsets(Editor.java:5679)
                                                                         at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1280)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8220)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4494)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4348)
                                                                         at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:89)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4323)
                                                                         at library.fragments.MapFragment$17$1.run(MapFragment.java:2156)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**as Requested**

This is how I assign value to string Variable, sorry for delay...

```
 private void getAddressFromLocation(final LatLng latlng, final EditText et) {
        et.setText(getString(R.string.text_waiting_for_address));
        et.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    final List<Address> list = gCoder.getFromLocation(
                            latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude, 1);
                    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                        address = list.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        Log.d("Endereço com cidade",address.toString());
                        preference.putCidade(address.getLocality());
                        preference.putEstado(address.getAdminArea().replace("State of ",""));
                        if (address.getAddressLine(0) != null) {
                            if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < address
                                        .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i))
                                            .append("\n");
                                }
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                            } else {
                                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0));
                            }
                        }


                        strAddress = sb.toString();
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace(",null", "");
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace("null", "");
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace("Unnamed", "");
                    }
                    if (getActivity() == null)
                        return;
```

Comment: Please add the full error to your question.

Comment: Everything looks good here, provide whole error message as well as part of code where you define et.

Comment: Post log error and try to log the values of ´strAddress´ to see what could be happening

Comment: Does your EditText use any TextWatchers?

Comment: Full error log posted

Comment: Does your EditText use any TextWatchers? searched the code and didn`t found one referente to TextWatchers.

Comment: @user2414726 the problem is not with setting the text, but with the spans you set. Show us the code where you prepare your text. As you can see, the error comes from `SpannableStringBuilder`

Comment: posted code where string is prepared...

Comment: Have you solved this?